# Are you there, asynchronously written value?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, thread-safety, async-await

The last couple of days I've been reading about async/await. Yesterday I found [this video](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/shows/three-essential-tips-for-async/tip-1-async-void-top-level-event-handlers-only) on Channel 9 what made wonder about some things. Please consider the slide below.

[image: Variable assignment in task]

Aside from the issues Lucian Wischik addresses, I wondered about variable assignment. Say we changed the `async void` into `async Task`, and added `await` before the `SendData` call. This enables us to get the stream, assign the variable `m_GetResponse`, wait for two seconds and print it. But what happens to the variable? It could be written by a different thread than it is read. Do we need some sort of a memory barrier here, make the variable volatile, or perhaps something else? Could it still be null when we print it?

Comment: I find both answers just as good, but I can't accept both answers. Sorry for that. =)

Comment: `async-await` does nothing about concurrency. That's a whole other problem on itself.

Comment: Related: [Memory barrier generators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6581848/memory-barrier-generators)

Comment: Also somewhat related: [Multiple Parallel.ForEach calls, MemoryBarrier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30250980/multiple-parallel-foreach-calls-memorybarrier)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the above example, it is safe to read the `m_GetResponse` because assignment will happen in same UI thread given that this is being called from UI.

This is because `SynchronizationContext` will be captured and continued when the async method resumes. So it is the same UI thread which writes the field and reading it. This isn't a problem here. Refer my [related answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19543729/2530848)

If called from non UI context, there is no guarantee that continuations will be ran in same thread. Usually it will be ran in ThreadPool thread. Given that the field read isn't volatile it is possible that you could get the previous value if necessary barriers are not inserted. But you don't need to worry about it because [TPL already does this for you](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/asyncawait-faq/) ([Web archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20120922073850/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/04/12/async-await-faq.aspx)).

From the above link:

> > Does the Task library automatically include memory barriers at certain points? E.g. would it include a memory barrier before and/or after a continuation?
>
> Yes, TPL includes the appropriate barriers when tasks are queued and at the beginning/end of task execution so that values are appropriately made visible.

<sub>(Answer by Stephen Toub, 1 May 2012)</sub>

So with TPL, you don't need to worry about memory barriers given that the Tasks are already completed. But if you're creating threads manually(which you shouldn't be doing) and dealing with threads directly --you'll have to insert necessary memory barriers.

Btw, `ReadToEnd` is a blocking call. I would not call it in UI thread. I'd use `ReadToEndAsync` instead to make your UI thread free. And I'll not use field here; I'll return the value from async method because every method call is just dependent on the parameter so it makes sense to return the value from the method.

So, your method will become something like the following

```
private async Task<string> SendDataAsync(string url)
{
    var request = WebRequest.Create(url);
    using(var response = await request.GetResponseAsync());
    using(var reader = new StreamReader(request.GetResponseStream());
        return await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
}
```

Comment: async/await does provide full memory barriers, so even in a non-UI context, if you use await there's no danger of not seeing the updated value. This is only a concern in a true race condition scenario where multiple threads could update the value.

Comment: @StephenCleary Thanks for the information. My quick google search finds [stephen toub's comment here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/04/12/async-await-faq.aspx). I've updated my answer please check.

Comment: The TPL blog is archived now [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/asyncawait-faq/) without the original comments. [The WayBack machine has it covered](https://web.archive.org/web/20150209074736/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/04/12/async-await-faq.aspx), though.

Comment: @tm1 thanks for mentioning the link is broken. Will update new link. Why can't msft provide redirect to the old links :(

Answer (score 3):

> But what happens to the variable? It could be written by a different
>   thread than it is read.

If `m_GetResponse` is a private field, and this class gets invoked multiple times by different threads, then yes, it is possible for the value to be "dirty" once someone else tries to read it. In order to make it thread-safe, you could `lock` around it. It seems that the authors intention was to invoke this from the UI thread only, hence him making `SendData` a private method. In that case, it is safe for `m_GetResponse` to be a private field, as the continuation of the async method which is responsible for the variable assignment will happen inside the UI message loop.

> Could it still be null when we print it?

It could be `null` if somewhere else in the code, someone sets that variable to `null`, as it's a class level variable. If you're talking about "could it be that we try to print `m_GetResponse` before `await` finishes the state-machine execution, then no. Again, i'm not sure the authors intentions were made around concurrent execution, but rather to show you `async-await` features.

> or perhaps something else?

In order to make it **thread safe**, you can simply remove the global variable, and return a local variable instead. `SendData` shouldn't be `async void` anyway, as it isn't used for event handler delegate assignment like `Button1_Click`.

You could do it better like this (i'll use `HttpClient` for simplicity):

```
public async Task<string> SendDataAsync(string url)
{
    var httpClient = new HttpClient();
    var response = await httpClient.GetAsync();
    return response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

Note you should remember that `async-await` isn't meant to address *parallelism*, it's more about *concurrency* and easing the use of naturally  async IO operations.