# Parallel.ForEach with modulo partitioning

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library, parallel.foreach

When using `Parallel.ForEach()` for 100 items using 4 threads, it will divide the list into 4 blocks (0-24, 25-49, 50-74, 75-99) of items, which means, that items 0, 25, 50 and 75 are processed in parallel.

Is it somehow possible to partition the items in a modulo way to handle those with lower indices first? Like:

```
Thread 1: 0, 5, 9,...
Thread 2: 1, 6, 10,...
Thread 3: 2, 7, 11,...
Thread 4: 3, 8, 12,...
```

Comment: Why would you need to do this?

Comment: Try specifing the partitioner: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381768(v=vs.110).aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd991604(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Chunk the list up yourself and send each chunk to parallel foreach?

Comment: Do not do it: each CPU core has its own cache with **16 byte** cacheline; so caches start feel (lock, check locks, reload etc.) each other. Usual rule is to put data for the different threads (tasks) as far as possible

Comment: What makes you think it does 0, 25, 50 and 75 first anyway?

Comment: @DavidG cause math :)

Comment: @RandRandom Um what? Pretty sure Parallel.forEach will pop off the first 4 items from the list and not jump to elements 25/50/75.

Comment: Hope the below link helps.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639768/parallel-foreach-ordered-execution

Comment: @DavidG I am afraid to tell you but thats not the case, Parallel.Foreach will try to split the list accross the threads which results in what Ben is talking about BUT it depends what the source is, it works that way with I guess everything that has a Count/Lenght and not an IEnumerable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This partitioning method is known as Round Robin, or Striping. The primary challenge of using this with `Parallel.ForEach()` is that `ForEach()` requires partitioners to support dynamic partitions, which would not be possible with this type of partitioning as the number of partitions must be fixed prior to execution of the loop.

One way to achieve this type of partitioning is to create a custom class derived from `System.Collections.Concurrent.Partitioner<TSource>` and use the `ParallelQuery.ForAll()` method, which does not have the dynamic partitioning support requirement. For most applications this should be equivalent to using `ForEach()`.

Below is an example of a custom `Partitioner` and a basic implementation. The `Partitioner` will generate the same number of partitions as the degree of parallelism.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace RoundRobinPartitioning
{
    public class RoundRobinPartitioner<TSource> : Partitioner<TSource>
    {
        private readonly IList<TSource> _source;

        public RoundRobinPartitioner(IList<TSource> source)
        {
            _source = source;
        }

        public override bool SupportsDynamicPartitions { get { return false; } }

        public override IList<IEnumerator<TSource>> GetPartitions(int partitionCount)
        {
            var enumerators = new List<IEnumerator<TSource>>(partitionCount);

            for (int i = 0; i < partitionCount; i++)
            {
                enumerators.Add(GetEnumerator(i, partitionCount));
            }

            return enumerators;
        }

        private IEnumerator<TSource> GetEnumerator(
            int partition,
            int partitionCount)
        {
            int position = partition;
            TSource value;

            while (position < _source.Count)
            {
                value = _source[position];
                position += partitionCount;
                yield return value;
            }
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var values = Enumerable.Range(0, 100).ToList();

            var partitioner = new RoundRobinPartitioner<int>(values);

            partitioner.AsParallel()
                .WithDegreeOfParallelism(4)
                .ForAll(value =>
                {
                    // Perform work here
                });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This does exactly, what I was asking in my question. What I forgot to mention: I'd like to Break(). Is that possible with ForAll()? I could set a break flag, which is checked as first in the action to be performed, but I'd still have to iterate over all items.

Answer (score 0):

What you probably want is to process the items in the `List<T>` in roughly ascending order. This is very easy with the [`Partitioner.Create`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.partitioner.create) API. Instead of passing the `List<T>` directly as the source of the `Parallel.ForEach`, you wrap it first in a `Partitioner.Create`:

```
ParallelOptions options = new()
{
    MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount
};

Partitioner<Item> partitioner = Partitioner.Create(list);

Parallel.ForEach(partitioner, options, item =>
{
    //...
});
```

This way the partitioning scheme is changed to [*chunk partitioning*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/custom-partitioners-for-plinq-and-tpl#kinds-of-partitioning), instead of the default for lists *range partitioning*. *Chunk partitioning* means that each worker thread grabs a small chunk of items from the beginning of the list, processes them, and then comes back to retrieve the next chunk etc. The chunks are initially small (only one item per chunk), and are getting progressively larger as the parallel operation unfolds.

It is also possible to configure the partitioner so that the workers take items from the list one at a time, by using the [`EnumerablePartitionerOptions.NoBuffering`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.enumerablepartitioneroptions) option:

```
Partitioner<Item> partitioner = Partitioner.Create(list,
    EnumerablePartitionerOptions.NoBuffering);
```

This is ideal in case processing each item takes a lot of time, because it optimizes the balancing of the work between the worker threads. It has the disadvantage of increased synchronization overhead for enumerating the list, but this overhead is dwarfed by the heavy work required for each individual item.

Microsoft has optimized the [`Parallel.ForEach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach) for very large lists, and for minuscule processing work for each item (for example ray-tracing 3D scenes to 2D images). That's why they opted for the *range partitioning* as the default, because it has zero synchronization overhead. For most practical business applications the default partitioning strategy is not the optimal, so the `Partitioner.Create` should be used instead.