# Parallel.ForEach and Parallel.For seem to queue items up in the individual threads

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, parallel.foreach

Consider the following code:

```
var items = Enumerable.Range(0, 200);
Parallel.ForEach(items, item => Console.WriteLine(item));
```

The items in the console end up in a random order. I am not sure how Parallel.ForEach enumerates but it looks like it is dividing the set up into queues in advance and then assigning each thread a queue. What I want is this to go in order. I don't need the *completion* in order, I want the items *taken from the enumerable* in order. If one thread is faster, that's fine. But 8 threads should always be running and only get an item when needed.

Now let's try this:

```
var items = Enumerable.Range(0, 200).ToArray();
Parallel.For(0, items.Length, item => Console.WriteLine(item));
```

Same result, total randomness. Ok, how about this:

```
var locker = new object();
var items = Enumerable.Range(0, 200).ToArray();
var index = 0;

Parallel.For(0, items.Length, _ => {

   // Throw away the index the parallel loop gave us, grab
   // the actual next item to process in a thread safe manner
   int indexToPull;
   lock(locker) {
      indexToPull = index++;
   }
   
   Console.WriteLine(items[indexToPull]);
});
```

Again, random. In my test, 0 and 1 came first but #2 was over half way through the list. Now I realize my example isn't perfect because the `Console.WriteLine` is really the output after the parallel thread finishes. I'm just trying to illustrate my point.

**Why does this matter?** For me, the items I am processing will take from 0.001 seconds to 2+ hours. I'm running into a situation where I start 8 threads using `ParallelOptions` but by the end of the enumeration the active thread count drops and drops. Eventually, 1 thread remains yet 1-2 unprocessed items still exist. So the CPU usage goes down and down. At the very end, item *n-2* is processing in the only remaining thread, yet I still have *n-1* and *n* to go.

**What I want:** I want to place the items in a more or less order of complexity and run them in parallel. I want each thread to grab 1 item at a time and always get the next one in the list. Again, when that thread completes is irrelevant. This should ensure that 8 threads are still running when the last item is enumerated. At this point threads will finish off and the running thread count will drop but no items will remain, so the time I spend running less than 8 threads is minimized.

Comment: Somewhat related: [Parallel.ForEach with modulo partitioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44416312/parallel-foreach-with-modulo-partitioning).

Comment: That's quite helpful. It shows that indeed my items are all setup into partitions and enumerated there. I don't really want to create my own partitions because I don't know the processing time of each item, but it could be better than random. What I really want is no partitions at all, each thread grabbing the next item when needed until items are all done. But yes this may help.

Comment: if you are using `Parallel.For/Foreach` to dispatch work to thread pool threads, and the processing takes between a millisecond and multiple hours, the longer work will starve the thread pool of threads.  My experience with PF/PFE (which was with about 40 units of work, with each taking maybe 50% to 2x of the average work processing time) is that the work dispatched in the order of the IEnum, processed appropriately, and then when that work is finished the thread gets more work dispatched to it as the initial processing finished.  Tracing on 2 core and 8 core machines had no surprises

Comment: Paul I have posted [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44416312/parallel-foreach-with-modulo-partitioning/77133832#77133832) in that question, that I could copy-paste as an answer to your question too. Which is probably not appropriate. :-)

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Indeed I needed to scroll past the accepted answer to yours! I will try that out and close the question if it does what I hope.