# Parallel.ForEach vs ActionBlock

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library, parallel.foreach, tpl-dataflow

For a given `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` and fixed amount of objects that need to be processed (i.e. have certain code executed on them) it would seem `Parallel.ForEach` and an `ActionBlock` would be equally useful.

What considerations would need to be taken into account when choosing one over the other?

Comment: They aren't the same *at all*. What are you trying to do? ActionBlock doesn't run process every item in a collection, it's used to asynchronously process items in a (potentially infinite) sequence, and actually construct pipelines of TransformBlock steps that terminate in an ActionBlock. That's why by default, each block uses only one worker task. Parallel.ForEach is completely unsuitable for async operations, it's meant to process a lot of in-memory data using all available cores

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, my mistake - perhaps a better phrasing would be, if Parallel.ForEach and ActionBlock are set to the same MaxDegreeOfParallelism and the amount of items posted to the ActionBlock and given to the ForEach to operate on are the same, what would be the difference in using them. I'll edit the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, both the [`Parallel.ForEach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach) and the [`ActionBlock<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.actionblock-1) can be used for the purpose of processing a list of items in parallel. Between these two the `Parallel.ForEach` is the more natural choise, because it communicates clearly its purpose and requires less study before using it. Both have gotchas that might catch you by surprise. Here are some things that you should have in mind:

1. The `Parallel.ForEach` processed the items in an order that depends on the type of the `source`. If it's a list or array the order will be quite peculiar, because the `Parallel.ForEach` will partition the list in ranges and will assign a worker task for each range (range partitioning). So you'll see the items to be processed like this: 1, 26, 51, 76, 2, 27, 52, 77..., instead of the quasi-sequential 1, 2, 4, 3, 5, 8, 6, 7 etc. If the source is an `IEnumerable<T>`, then the order will be the natural start-to-end. The `ActionBlock<T>` processes the items in the order that you `Post` them, so there are no surprises there.
2. When the `source` is an `IEnumerable<T>`, the `Parallel.ForEach` uses [chunk partitioning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/custom-partitioners-for-plinq-and-tpl#kinds-of-partitioning) by default, meaning that it doesn't grab just one item from the `source` at a time. It accumulates items in small chunks, and then starts processing them. This might catch you by surprise if for example your `source` is a `BlockingCollection<T>`. You will add an item in the collection and the `Parallel.ForEach` won't process it immediately, and you'll wonder why. The `ActionBlock<T>` takes items for its own buffer one-by-one, so no surprises there.
3. The `ActionBlock<T>` by default has [`MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 1`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.executiondataflowblockoptions.maxdegreeofparallelism) (i.e. no parallelism). On the contrary the `Parallel.ForEach` by default has [`MaxDegreeOfParallelism = -1`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions.maxdegreeofparallelism) (i.e. unlimited parallelism). The `Parallel.ForEach` has by far [the most dangerous default](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/72981), because if you forget to configure the `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` it will quickly saturate your `ThreadPool`. With a saturated `ThreadPool`, other concurrent operations of your program will stutter.
4. The `ActionBlock<T>` has the annoying "[by design](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/29619)" behavior of swallowing any `OperationCancelledException`s thrown by the `action`. So if processing an item can fail with an `OperationCancelledException`, i.e. if this exception denotes failure instead of cancellation, the `ActionBlock<T>` will complete happily with no exception like nothing happened, hiding from you that actually the processing of some items failed.

The peculiarities of the `Parallel.ForEach` that I mentioned earlier can be fixed easily by wrapping the `source` in an appropriate `Partitioner`, as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44416312/parallel-foreach-with-modulo-partitioning/77133832#77133832). A more drastical fix is to switch to the newer [`Parallel.ForEachAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreachasync) API. Although the `Parallel.ForEachAsync` has `Async` in its name, it can process synchronous workloads just as easily and efficiently. Just return a `ValueTask.CompletedTask` from the `body`, and `Wait` the resulting `Task`. The `Parallel.ForEachAsync` employs no surprising chunking/partitioning strategies ([not documented](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/72806) though). It processes the items in the natural start-to-end order. It is also less aggressive with owning the `ThreadPool`, since by default it has `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` equal to [`Environment.ProcessorCount`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.processorcount), which is a sensible default for most scenarios. Its worker tasks are [synchronized asynchronously](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/pull/82501) when they take items from the `source`, so if the source is an empty `BlockingCollection<T>` only one thread will be blocked. It lacks some functionality that the `Parallel.ForEach` has, like breaking and getting the [`LowestBreakIteration`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallelloopresult.lowestbreakiteration), but these features are rarely used in practice.